# Is it possible to get https response using requests module when web page in JS

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to capture a https response using `requests.get` but I am not getting the same information as I see in web browser . Actual web page will have username ,password fields and a submit button . Webpage is written in java script.

So , I wanted to know whether it is possible to capture the https response using requests module ? Any help would be highly appreciated

```
>>> cafile='/etc/pki/tls/mycertfile.pem'
>>> import requests
>>> r=requests.get('https://10.22.156.151/performance',verify=cafile)
/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:344: SubjectAltNameWarning: Certificate for 10.22.156.151 has no `subjectAltName`, falling back to check for a `commonName` for now. This feature is being removed by major browsers and deprecated by RFC 2818. (See https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/497 for details.)
  SubjectAltNameWarning
>>> r
<Response [200]>
>>> r.text
u'<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<!--\n# Copyright (c) 2001-2018 Hewlett Packard Enterprise Development LP\n-->\n<head>\n  <meta charset="utf-8"/>\n  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>\n\n  <script src="/js/mocha_history_compat.js"></script>\n\n  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/noauth/theme/airwave/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />\n\n\n  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/mercury.1516735736.css" />\n\n\n  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/helpdesk/style/style.1516735737.css"/>\n  <!--[if !IE]><!-->\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/helpdesk/style/not_ie.1516735737.css"/>\n  <!--<![endif]-->\n\n  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/frappe/style/style.1516735769.css"/>\n\n\n  <script src="/mercury.1516735736.js"></script>\n\n\n\n  <script src="/frappe/script/module_frappe.1516735769.js"></script>\n\n\n\n  <script src="/helpdesk/script/third_party/highcharts/highcharts.1516735737.js"></script>\n  <script src="/helpdesk/script/third_party/highcharts/highcharts-more.1516735737.js"></script>\n  <script src=""></script>\n\n\n\n  <script type="text/javascript">\n    window.mocha_app_args = {\n   "dev_mode" : null,\n   "accept_language_locale" : null,\n   "vendor_name" : "Aruba",\n   "mocha_en_mtime" : 1516735737,\n   "short_copyright_info" : "&copy; 2018 Hewlett Packard Enterprise Development LP",\n   "supported_languages" : {\n      "ptBR" : 0,\n      "zht" : 1,\n      "tr" : 1,\n      "it" : 1,\n      "zh" : 1,\n      "es" : 1,\n      "nl" : 0,\n      "ko" : 1,\n      "en" : 1,\n      "fr" : 1,\n      "de" : 1,\n      "ja" : 1\n   },\n   "cert_auth" : {\n      "client_cert_present" : false,\n      "client_cert_valid" : false,\n      "client_cert_enabled" : false,\n      "use_two_factor_auth" : false,\n      "client_cert_required" : false\n   },\n   "short_product_name" : "AMP",\n   "theme" : "airwave",\n   "product_name" : "AirWave Management Platform"\n}\n;\n  </script>\n\n  <script src="/js/mocha_app.js"></script>\n\n<!-- remove espresso later -->\n<script src="/espresso/script/module_espresso.js"></script>\n\n</head>\n<body class="fontface">\n  <input type="text" name="mocha_history_state" id="mocha_history_state" style="display:none">\n\n  <div id="app-container" class="off_canvas_wrap awapp-folder-breadcrumbs-parent">\n    <div id="app-page-container" class="page inner_wrap">\n      <awapp-folder-breadcrumbs></awapp-folder-breadcrumbs>\n      <awapp-folder-breadcrumbs-menu></awapp-folder-breadcrumbs-menu>\n      \n      <div id="app-main-content">\n        <div id="amp-nav">\n          <!-- angular sidenav -->\n          <awapp-sidenav></awapp-sidenav>\n        </div>\n\n        <div class="right-container">\n          <!-- existing pages -->\n          <div id="right-container">\n            <!-- angular page -->\n            <ng-view></ng-view>\n          </div>\n        </div>\n      </div>\n    </div>\n  </div>\n  <div class=\'copyright\'>\n<div>\n&copy; 2018 Hewlett Packard Enterprise Development LP - <a target="_blank" href="http://www.arubanetworks.com/">http://www.arubanetworks.com/</a>\n<br/>\n\nNeither AirWave Wireless nor Aruba Networks, an HP company is connected, affiliated or related to Airwave Solutions Limited in any way whatsoever.\n\n</div>\n</div>\n\n\n\n</body>\n</html>\n'
>>> print r.text
```

Comment: `requests` is just an HTTP client, not a browser (it can't run js). You may have to use `selenium`.

Answer (score 1):

As t.m.adam mentioned `requests` is just an HTTP client, so it just scraps the HTML of the website when sending GET request.

for your purpose, you need a browser in order to run the javascript.
Selenium is a good option but not the best.

make sure you check a list of headless browsers [here](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers).